# PowerShell to check for missing ShadowCopies

Tags: powershell

Trying to check for SMB shares (DC's and member servers) that are missing Shadow Copies. Can't get the PowerShell filter just right.

This is the closest I've come. I'm still getting SYSVOL shares in the list.

```
Get-SmbShare -Special $False | FL Name,Path,ShadowCopy | Where-Object {(-not $_.ShadowCopy) -and ($_.Path -notlike "*sysvol*")}
```

I'm expecting the output to be like:

```
Name       : test
Path       : C:\test
ShadowCopy : False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the formatting cmdlet's in the middle of a pipeline. By using `fl`, you are essentially creating an array of strings. The `where` clause operates on those strings.

Most likely, you meant to do something like this

```
Get-SmbShare | 
    Where-Object {!($_.ShadowCopy) -and ($_.Path -notlike '*sysvol*')} | 
    fl name, path, shadowcopy
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I added back the -Special $False. Perfect!